# Images disappear offscreen in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

This is my code, though Firefox added weird classes to each for some reason:

```
<img id="share_facebook" class="gknwrycuvfcesykaisun" src="http://localhost:80/graphics/share/facebook.png"></img>
<img id="share_google" src="http:/localhost:80/graphics/share/google.png"></img>
<img id="share_pinterest" class="gknwrycuvfcesykaisun" src="http://localhost:80/graphics/share/pinterest.png"></img>
<img id="share_tumblr" class="gknwrycuvfcesykaisun" src="http://localhost:80/graphics/share/tumblr.png"></img>
<img id="share_twitter" class="gknwrycuvfcesykaisun" src="http://localhost:80/graphics/share/twitter.png"></img>
<img id="share_email" src="http://localhost:80//graphics/share/email.png"></img>
```

In Chrome, this works as expected, but in Firefox, the images don't show at all. When I click on them with the document inspector, there's a grey information box that shows at the top left of the screen which suggests that the images are outside of the document or offscreen or such.

There's no special styles on these and I've even tried moving them outside of all the content of my page and putting them right below the BODY tag as well as removing the weird extra class values that Firefox adds, but at best the Google and email images show and none of the others.

Hovering over the image source address in the inspector shows a popup image for Google and email and the rest say "could not load the image". If I cut and paste the value and load it in a new tab, I can see the image fine.

I cleared the cache for "all time" for every category and still nothing. What is going on!?

Comment: There might be an unclosed tag/attribute there. You might want to double check your code. Right now, I can't really tell from what I'm seeing.

Comment: That's the problem though... it's just a bunch of image declarations. Why would they be off screen and partially visible? Why is firefox refusing to load some, but loads the others fine?

Comment: Do you have any other code ? I'm not sure simple image declarations do this. I've never got that issue before. Try to Copy as HTML in FFX devtools and tell me what you see.

Comment: Copying it just copies what I see in the inspector/source (which is what I pasted above). I'm not sure what you mean by "other code". This is part of a complex new web service I'm writing and there are tons of other images all on the same page that load fine.

Comment: The code you use to generate images ? I'm sure there are missing quotes in your code, or some kind of silly error like that.

Comment: There is no code used to generate images. All the code I use is as listed above. I don't see any missing quotes.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who runs into this question like I did, it was [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23039437/firefox-says-could-not-load-image-for-some-images-adds-weird-classes-automati/23039860#23039860).

The short answer is: Adblock.

Comment: Holy moly. I'd spent 20 minutes saying WTF, and I'm sure I could have spent 20 more before discovering this. Thanks!

Comment: That'll learn me to call my images `ad1.png`, `ad2.png` etc. Thanks!

Comment: Did you realize?? You are suggesting the answer of the same person who asked this question (he asked 2 questions). LOL

Comment: @Aayush hahaha I never noticed!