# Firefox says "Could Not Load Image" for some images, adds weird classes automatically

Tags: html, firefox

I've tried several times and several ways, but can't figure this out. The below set of images load perfectly in non-firefox browsers, but ALL of them are invisible in firefox. If I bring up the document inspector and hover the mouse over the url, the images pop up for only google and email (which are the only two that don't have that weird class on them).

So I guess the question is: why is firefox adding a weird class to my images (just these, all others on the page work fine) and why don't any of them show up in this area?

```
   <div id="share_icons">
            <img class="gknwrycuvfcesykaisun" src="http://localhost:80/graphics/share/facebook.png" id="share_facebook">
            <img src="http://localhost:80/graphics/share/google.png" id="share_google">
            <img class="gknwrycuvfcesykaisun" src="http://localhost:80/graphics/share/pinterest.png" id="share_pinterest">
            <img class="gknwrycuvfcesykaisun" src="http://localhost:80/graphics/share/tumblr.png" id="share_tumblr">
            <img class="gknwrycuvfcesykaisun" src="http://localhost:80/graphics/share/twitter.png" id="share_twitter">
            <img src="http://localhost:80/graphics/share/email.png" id="share_email" pop="Send a link to this list to friends via e-mail. <b>Note:</b> recipients must already be users of the site or your view settings must allow public views for them to see it!">
        </div>
```

Here is the calculated CSS of the #share_icons area:

```
#share_icons {
width: 150px;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
* {
border: 0px none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Another thing I noticed, when I click on any of the images in this area, the pop up box for the inspector which usually hovers over the element where it is on the page is at the top left of the screen as if the images are all off screen somewhere.

Already tried clearing the cache completely. Also tried manually loading the image urls in Firefox and the images load and display fine if I do this. I've also moved the image tags to other places on the page to make sure this isn't a nested CSS thing.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Sorry to jump in so quickly, but I noticed something odd and FINALLY discovered the reason. Adblock was blocking the images most likely because I had accidentally clicked it and filtered it out.

I'll leave this question because it may be helpful to others.

Comment: As an addendum, you might've run into this for the same reasons as me. I nailed it down to "Fanboy's Social Blocking List" with Adblock's "Open Blockable Items" widget.

Comment: I have lost one whole hour because of this. Tried every URL combination I could think off. Thank you, thank you!

Comment: Thank you! For me it was Privacy Badger blocking the images I was seeing as supposedly 404.

Comment: Firefox' Facebook container addon also will prevent images from Instagram or Facebook to show.

Comment: For me it was stupid Urban VPN which has inbuilt ad blocker.. Thanks a ton! =)

Answer (score 5):

Disable **AdBlock** for that current page you load. Image gets displayed after refresh. I just tried it and it is working.