# “Could not load image” img src URL Ionic

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I’m trying to display an URL image on my page using img src, but the image doesn’t appear even though the URL passed to img src is valid. Here’s the message I see when using Element Inspector in my browser:

[image]

Comment: Try to disable adblock Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23039860/4838471

Comment: Did you try `https` ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help guys! I found out there was an error with the HTTP request, and what I had to do was to change the meta tag to this:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
   img-src * 'self' data: https:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
   style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

Answer (score -1):

try using `<ion-img>` tag and if you are assigning the url with a variable make sure you to use `[]` with `src`, for example:

```
<ion-img [src]=''></ion-img>
```

Hope this helps.